# how to resolve sdk error

Tags: ios, xcode

i am adding a a swiper sdk in my application. when i run its test app it work fine but when i import my file to it .get error

```
ld: library not found for -lCardAnalyLib1
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i searched for the error but dint get how to resolve. nd some time armv error

> (null): Library not found for -lCardAnalyLib1 it is **.a typefile**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "AudioAnalyLib.h"
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h
these are pre imported file but if i import any other file get above error
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the .a file to your target.  Choose the Build Phases tab of the target in Xcode, open up the Link Binary With Libraries section, and add your library file.

Comment: it is pre added in that but then also it shows the same error

Comment: Is the path to the .a file set correctly in the Library Search Paths?

Comment: how to check that sorry i am not that much experienced

Comment: In the Build Settings tab for the target there's a Search Paths section and that's one of the entries.